# Format one column with another column in Pyspark dataframe

Tags: python, dataframe, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have business case, where one column to be updated based on the value of another 2 columns. I have given an example as below:

```
+-------------------------------+------+------+---------------------------------------------------------------------+
|ErrorDescBefore                |name  |value |ErrorDescAfter                                                       |
+-------------------------------+------+------+---------------------------------------------------------------------+
|The error is in %s value is %s.|xx    |z     |The error is in xx value is z.                                       |
|The new cond is in %s is %s.   |y     |ww    |The new cond is in y is ww.                                        |
+-------------------------------+------+------+---------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

The `ErrorDescBefore` `column` has 2 `placeholders` i.e. `%s`, the `placeholders` to be filled by `columns` `name` and `value`. The output is in `ErrorDescAfter`.

Can we achieve this in Pyspark. I tried `string_format` and realized that is not the right approach. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thank You

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you know that the format in the `ErrorDescBefore` column will remain consistent, then you can `split` ErrorDescBefore on the string `%s`, and concatenate each item with your `name` and `value` columns:

```
df.withColumn(
    'ErrorDescAfter',
    F.concat(
        F.split(F.col('ErrorDescBefore'), '%s').getItem(0),
        F.col('name'),
        F.split(F.col('ErrorDescBefore'), '%s').getItem(1),
        F.col('value'),
        F.split(F.col('ErrorDescBefore'), '%s').getItem(2),
    )
)

+-------------------------------+----+-----+------------------------------+
|ErrorDescBefore                |name|value|ErrorDescAfter                |
+-------------------------------+----+-----+------------------------------+
|The error is in %s value is %s.|xx  |z    |The error is in xx value is z.|
|The new cond is in %s is %s.   |y   |ww   |The new cond is in y is ww.   |
+-------------------------------+----+-----+------------------------------+
```

Answer (score 1):

You can always use an UDF for a custom need, like this one:

```
spark = SparkSession.builder.appName("DateDataFrame").getOrCreate()
data = [
    ("The error is in %s value is %s.", "xx", "z"),
    ("The new cond is in %s is %s.", "y", "ww"),
]
df = spark.createDataFrame(data, ['ErrorDescBefore', 'name', 'value'])

format_udf = udf(lambda str, name, value: str.replace('%s', name, 1).replace('%s', value, 1))

df.withColumn("ErrorDescAfter", format_udf(col("ErrorDescBefore"), col("name"), col("value"))).show(truncate=False)
```

Result:

```
+-------------------------------+----+-----+------------------------------+
|ErrorDescBefore                |name|value|ErrorDescAfter                |
+-------------------------------+----+-----+------------------------------+
|The error is in %s value is %s.|xx  |z    |The error is in xx value is z.|
|The new cond is in %s is %s.   |y   |ww   |The new cond is in y is ww.   |
+-------------------------------+----+-----+------------------------------+
```

Answer (score 1):

You can split `ErrorDescBefore` into an array with `%s` as the separator, and then use the `concat` function to connect its elements with `name` and `value`.

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F

...
df = df.withColumn('ErrorDescAfter', F.split('ErrorDescBefore', '%s')).withColumn(
    'ErrorDescAfter',
    F.concat(F.col('ErrorDescAfter')[0], 'name', F.col('ErrorDescAfter')[1], 'value', F.col('ErrorDescAfter')[2])
)
```